# How do I test only the seeds in my dbt project?

Tags: dbt

How can I test only the seeds folder on my dbt projet??
[image]
[image]

I've used `dbt test`, but it tests the entire project (seeds included). I've used `dbt test --select seeds` but it says: `Nothing to do. Try checking your model configs and model specification args`

Is there any way to test only the seeds folder?

I've searched everywhere but I couldn't find anything regarding this

Answer (score 1):

You should refer to the following dbt docs: https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/node-selection/syntax

TL;DR:

`dbt test -s ./seeds`

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/node-selection/test-selection-examples):

```
# Run tests on all seeds, which use the 'seed' materialization
$ dbt test --select config.materialized:seed
```